# Trying to display a line in canvas unit circle with a known angle

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

If I know the angle, say 30 degrees, I want to display a line with that angle in the quadrant.
I have tried:

```
let angle = 30;
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2); //Center point
ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle)); // x and y?;  I need the distance?
```

Listen, Trig really is a new concept for me and I would appreciate any advice.
Here is my canvas...

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // width and height are 400
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();

// The Vertical line to create quadrants
ctx.moveTo((canvas.width/2),0);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height);


// The Horizontal Line to create quadrants
ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height/2);
ctx.lineTo((canvas.width), canvas.height/2);

// The circle contained in my canvas
ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, canvas.width/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);


ctx.stroke(); // Make line visible, otherwise for shapes use stroke

// Radians to degrees
function toDegrees(radians){
    return radians * Math.PI/180
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I found it easier to convert the radians first, then to draw the line. Remember, Unit circle coordinates range in x and y values from -1 to 1. We are scaling this up, so to get the actual position on the canvas, we need to do 2 things:

1) Multiply the unit circle coordinates * the center coordinates.
2) add the center coordinates to that value

I used a red stroke style so you can see it a bit better:

**Full Code**

```js
      let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

      canvas.width = 512;
      canvas.height = 512;

      ctx.beginPath();

      // The Vertical line to create quadrants
      ctx.moveTo((canvas.width/2),0);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height);


      // The Horizontal Line to create quadrants
      ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height/2);
      ctx.lineTo((canvas.width), canvas.height/2);

      // The circle contained in my canvas
      ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, canvas.width/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);


      ctx.stroke(); // Make line visible, otherwise for shapes use stroke

      //Degrees to radians
      function toRadians(degrees) {
          return (degrees * Math.PI)/180
      }

      //Angle in degrees
      let angle = 315;
      //Angle in Radians
      let angleToRad = toRadians(angle)
      //Changes the color to red
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
      //Starts a new line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2); //Center point
      ctx.lineTo((canvas.width/2) + (Math.cos(angleToRad) * canvas.height / 2), (canvas.height/2) - (Math.sin(angleToRad) * canvas.height / 2)); 
      ctx.stroke();
```

**Just the things i added:**

```js
 //Degrees to radians
      function toRadians(degrees) {
          return (degrees * Math.PI)/180
      }

      //Angle in degrees
      let angle = 315;
      //Angle in Radians
      let angleToRad = toRadians(angle)
      //Changes the color to red
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
      //Starts a new line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2); //Center point
      ctx.lineTo((canvas.width/2) + (Math.cos(angleToRad) * canvas.height / 2), (canvas.height/2) - (Math.sin(angleToRad) * canvas.height / 2)); 
      ctx.stroke();
```